# Group and Map into Object with an inner aggregate Object

Tags: c#, linq

I have many `Object1A`, say `IEnumerable<Object1A>`.

```
public class Object1A {
     public string text;
     public datetime date;
     public decimal percent;
     public Object3 obj;
}
```

Many of these objects have the same text, date, and percent, but have a different obj. I want to transform the list such that the output will be a `IEnumerable<Object1B>` where

```
public class Object1B{
     public string text;
     public datetime date;
     public decimal percent;
     public IEnumerable<Object3> objs;
}
```

My current apporach is a bit clunky, and listed below

```
IEnumerable<Object1A> a = GetSomeConstruct();
var lookup = a.ToLookup( t => t.text);

var b = new List<Object1b>();
foreach(var group in lookup){

   var itemA = group.first();  

   var itemB = new Object1b(){
          text = itemA.text,
          date = itemA.date,
          percent = itemA.percent
    };

   itemB.objs = pair.Select(t => t.obj);
   b.Add(itemB);
}
```

Can this approach be refined? It doesn't seem to run to slow, but it seems like it could be better. I'm looking for a more terse approach if possible.

---

edit: yeah, this was  a dumb question, cudos to the downvote....

simple answer

```
        var b_objects = a_objects.GroupBy(t => new {t.Text})
            .Select( t => new Object1B
                    { Text = t.Key.Text,
                      Percent = t.First().Percent,
                      Date = t.First().Date,
                      Objs = t.Select( o => o.Obj).ToList()
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess you want something like this?

```
var b = from a in GetSomeConstruct()
        group a.obj by new { a.text, a.date, a.percent } into grp
        select new Object1B
        {
            text = grp.Key.text,
            date = grp.Key.date,
            percent = grp.Key.percent,
            objs = grp
        };
```

You can use anonymous types with join and group by. Their `GetHashCode` and `Equals` overloads operate on each member.

Comment: you're right in that I could use all the repeated properties as a key. I'm a bit concerned about its efficiency - because I have closer to 10 repleated properties for each unique inner object. (its a nice solution for the exact question asked though)

Comment: `GroupBy` uses a hash table internally just like `Lookup`